# Multiple apps still show in output when updating despite being "removed"

Tags: wine, uninstall, gnome-terminal, purge, runescape

I downloaded Wine and Runescape when I first got my computer, and haven't had a need for either and tried to remove them. Yet everytime I update it says connecting to both of them in the terminal output. Any attempt to remove them says they aren't installed, or sometimes in wine's case I get

```
> virtual packages like 'wine' can't be removed
```

I've looked for alternate solutions for properly purging, but it seems like every post has contradicting advice and claims that these purges will nuke parts of your system.

Tips?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt autoremove --purge package-name` will clear all the traces.
After this run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

The first command will list the packages it will be removing. Have a eye over those. If some package needed for another app is removed, then the second command will fix it. Essentially the package manager `apt` will download them back.

**Warning** don't ever try `sudo apt autoremove --purge python3`. This will definitely nuke your system. And in most cases these damages are irreversible. Imagine `apt` is missing/not working properly and hence you cannot restore the missing packages. You will have the same situation when executing `sudo apt autoremove --purge python3`.

When it comes to removing wine, do the purge command I mentioned above, and then delete then `.wine` folder in the home directory.